# FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is not working

Tags: java, android

I'm having an issue with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. When the user launch the app a screen appear for them to login or register. Once the user login into the app I want all the previous Activities to close. When I press the back button it logs the user out and takes them back to the LAUNCHER activity.

Below is my login Activity:

```
public class login extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        //Declaring global variables to be used throughout asyn class

         String email;
         String password;
         UserFunctions userFunction;
         JSONObject json;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging into Thryfting...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            publishProgress();

                email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);


            // check for login response
            try {
                //if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        


                    }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pDialog.dismiss();

                 email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                 password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                 userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                 json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

                try {
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                     // Launch Dashboard Screen
                    Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Timeline.class);

                    // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                    dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(dashboard);

                    // Close Login Screen
                    finish();
                    }
                    else{
                    // Error in registration
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Email and password combination", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve but it feels like you're misunderstanding the effect of FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. You usually use it to get back to an Activity that is already in stack instead of starting a new instance of this Activity on top of the stack.

Comment: @egor Once the user is logged in I want the main, login and registration Activities to be closed. So when they press the back button it does not log them out

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling `finish()` to your login acivity then `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` will not work.

Remove the `finsh()` from your login activity from here

```
startActivity(dashboard);

// Close Login Screen
finish(); //remove this
```

in your onPostExceute method.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using addflags to clear activities try this one

```
dashboard.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

this will surely solve your problem.